# how to force delete a directory when it says permission denined -> even with root access

Tags: permissions, sudo, root, delete

I was just working on my kernel project. when I extracted the .iso file, I got everything I expected, all except for that the "boot" and "system" directories were with some lock symbol to free up space, I deleted the files (outside the directories) but unable to delete those 2 folders in the "files" application - even the content.

While using `rmdir` in the terminal, it says "permission denied", even with root access. (also tried "`sudo rmdir`").

How to fix, please?

Comment: What is the output of `lsattr` on the contents of the directory that you would like to delete? If you see something like `----i--------—-`, then you're dealing with immutable files and you'll need to use `chattr` to *ch*ange their *attr*ibutes 

Comment: getting just "e". but don't know what to change @matigo .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try removing it recursively and forcefully:

```
 sudo rm -rf /path/to/directory
```

If `sudo` is not working then try logging in as root to recursively delete the directory:

```
sudo su                  # Login as root 
rm -rf /path/to/directory           # remove the directory
```